# Jenkins multibranch pipeline with pipeline-github plugin: limitation on first run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a multibranch pipeline and I am using pipeline-github plugin to trigger by comments on PR and it's fine.
Now I would like to trigger **only** by PR comments.
But there is a limitation

> The Pull Request's job/build must have run at least once for the trigger to be registered. If an initial run never takes place then the trigger won't be registered and cannot pickup on any comments made.

In my configuration, PR are discovered and not triggered by the basic-branch-build-strategies plugin so config.xml is created in the job/PR directory.
So I think I am missing only to register the trigger. How can I do programmatically? Is there a way to force a "fake" first run? What is the steps that I miss?
Thanks in advance, Pierluigi

Comment: You can quickly abort the job if it wasn't triggered by a comment. In this case the job would run on every commit and comment, but only comment-triggered jobs would actually build something.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, can you provide an example/documentation to abort, please? Is it possible to run this only on the first trigger?

Answer (score 1):

solved with your suggestion adding:

```
def buildCause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()[0]
echo "Build caused by: ${buildCause}\n"
if ("${buildCause}".contains("github.trigger.IssueCommentCause")) {
     echo "Build will proceed..."
} else {
     currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
     error('Skipping build…')
}
```

maybe it can be improved but it's fine